# How to find same text in excel with formula

Tags: excel, windows, formula

Is there an excel formula to search for almost the same text. My sample text is MCT (15pcs), MCT (20pcs), MCT (50pcs). I want to find text that has an MCT value excluding (*number*). so if I get an MCT, then all values on MCT (15), MCT (20), MCT (50) will be displayed.

```
------------------
     A      | B  |
------------------
MCT (15pcs) | 20 |
------------------
MCT (20pcs) | 12 |
------------------
MCT (50pcs) | 9  |
```

Please give your expert help.

Comment: If you have the latest version of Excel (MS 365) you should have got a function called `FILTER()`.

Comment: Thanks JvdV. But I want activities like this, if I enter mct text, then all values on MCT (15pcs), MCT (20pcs), MCT (50pcx) filled in col A and B, will be displayed.

Comment: Sure, that's what `FILTER()` does =). Research it.

Comment: Yes. Thanks JvdV

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the MCT data ranges from A1:B3 you can use the following formulas:

You can use this formula elsewhere and it will produce a list of all the items that contain  "MCT" (adjust the range as needed)

`=FILTER(A1:B3,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("MCT",A1:A3)))`

This formula you would lay in an additional column beside the table and it will tell you each row that contains "MCT" within column A. You can use this column to filter and sort the data table.

`=IF(FIND("MCT",A1),"MCT","None")`

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer. After doing a detailed search, I found a formula that could accurately filter the values I wanted. By creating dynamic filter search. Finally done. Thanks to those who are willing to give good and great answers.